# How to define AnswersWithDelay for a void returning method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

So, I want to mimic in Mockito a method that is making a network call and is waiting for it to complete before returning. I found this nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50530261/4433222 that suggests using `AnswersWithDelay`.

Issue is though that I struggle to define a method's behavior for a method that returns void. `AnswersWithDelays` constructor requires a parameter of `Answer<Object>` type, and I wasn't able to find how to set it as void. Any clues?

Comment: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.2.4/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12

Comment: @JBNizet - I read the linked section. It doesn't answer my question as I still need to construct `AnswersWithDelays`! Also, write a comment when you downvote, so I know how not to ask questions, please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, AnswersWithDelay is an internal class of Mockito. So you should not use it directly. Instances of this class are supposed to be created by using the factory methods in the public `AdditionalAnswers` class.

So all you need is

```
doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(delay, invocation -> null)).when(mockObject).doSomething();
```

Comment: Note: `delay` here is in miliseconds and not seconds. I learnt it the hard way,

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59426498/379173) answer, with a draft test class.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class MockDelayVoidTest {
    
    @MockBean
    private Object myMock;

    void test(){
        Mockito.doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.answersWithDelay(1000, invocationOnMock -> {
            //here you can customize the behavior of your mock method
            return null;}))
                .when(myMock).toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way may be,

```
Mockito.doAnswer(invocation -> {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
        return null;
    }).when(mock).doSomething();
```